# cut file and overwrite file

Tags: stdout, cut

Let's say I have `file.txt`

```
water 1
lorem 0
ipsum 0
```

I cut the last column and redirect output to file itself with this:

```
cut -d' ' -f 1 file.txt > file.txt
```

I expect current content of `file.txt` is

```
water
lorem
ipsum
```

However, I got blank file in `file.txt`

Comment: Specifically, [this answer about `>`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/186126/86440).

Comment: So I need to create temp_file as buffer and rename temp_file to actuall name file.

Comment: So the solution for my case is ```cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt> temp && mv temp file.txt```

Comment: or if you have GNU awk: `awk -i inplace '{print $1}' file.txt`

Comment: There is a utility for this: `cut -d' ' -f 1 file.txt | sponge file.txt`. `sponge` collects all the output, then writes it to the named file (**no** redirection) *after* the previous program has finished reading it.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant and it’s mentioned in the linked answer ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt  It does.  I wondered why the OP went with the temp_file solution, though.